# Error in MS SQl 11.0 given code: 'unix_timestamp' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, unix-timestamp

I got the SQL query from another developer and there was unix_timestamp function, because this query returns a list of objects from database in the exact period of time. Query doesn't work because of the SQL error 195: 'unix_timestamp' is not a recognized built-in function.

```
n.created>unix_timestamp('2019-02-28') and n.created<unix_timestamp('2019-09-01')
```

Answer (score 1):

"unix_timestamp" is a built in function on MySQL - it **isn't** on SQLserver.

Here's the code to get the unix timestamp *now*:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01', GETUTCDATE()) AS unix_timestamp
```

You can either create a user defined function to do this and use the query as-is or you can just modify the query like so:

```
n.created>(DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01', '2019-02-28')) and n.created<(DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01','2019-09-01'))
```

Comment: So, is there any solution to activate this code on SQL-server?

Comment: @lisa Apologies - I submitted too quickly, I've added in some code which should let you achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: what does this 1970 year mean there?

Comment: @lisa unix timestamps are measured in seconds since 01/01/1970 - so by passing that date to SQL's DATEDIFF function and asking it to give us the number of seconds between then and the two dates from the original query we're getting (essentially - there's some stuff around leap seconds but it shouldn't be an issue here hopefully) the same result

Answer (score 0):

Unix timestamps are not particularly useful in SQL Server.  You can add a computed column to convert this to a `datetime` data type:

```
alter table t add created_dt as (dateadd(second, created, '1970-01-01')) persisted;

create index t_created_dt on t(created_dt);
```

This then allows you to write:

```
n.created_dt > '2019-02-28' and
n.created_dt < '2019-09-01';
```

Otherwise, the solution by motobatsu is a good solution.